# Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have this HTTP Request and I want to display only the Authorization section (base64 Value) : any help ?

```
This Request is stored on a variable called hreq
```

I have tried this :

```
reg = re.search(r"Authorization:\sBasic\s(.*)\r", hreq)
print reg.group()
```

but doesn't work

Here is the request :

```
HTTP Request: 
Path: /dynaform/custom.js 
Http-Version: HTTP/1.1 
Host: 192.168.1.254 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Referer: http://domain.com/userRpm/StatusRpm.htm 
Authorization: Basic YWhtEWa6MDfGcmVlc3R6bGH
```

---

I want to display the value *YWhtEWa6MDfGcmVlc3R6bGH* 
Please I need your help 
thanks in advance experts

Comment: Is a linebreak part of a validation? If not, just get rid of it. You don't use any validation for the beginning of the line, so ..

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `\r` at the end of the regex, in Linux it is a `\n` and it might break your script since you were expecting `\r` instead of `\n`:

```
>>> reg = re.search(r"Authorization:\sBasic\s(.*)", a)
>>> reg.groups()
('YWhtEWa6MDfGcmVlc3R6bGH ',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` is probably throwing things off; there probably isn't a carriage return at the end of the request (but it's hard to say from this end). Try removing it or using `$` (end-of-input) instead.

You can use this [online Python regex tester](http://www.pythonregex.com/) to try your inputs by hand before putting them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your whole input text maybe `/(\b[ ].*)$/` could help

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lY7fU9)**

**`[ ]`** match a space character present in the text. followed by

**`.*`** any character (except newline) followed by

**`$`** the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers :), actually I got an error msg

but anyway I'm gonna show what exactly I wanna do,

### **here is the script :**

## !/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *

from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception

from scapy import HTTP

my_iface="wlan0"

count=0

def pktTCP(pkt):

```
global count

count=count+1

if HTTP.HTTPRequest or HTTP.HTTPResponse in pkt:
     src=pkt[IP].src
     srcport=pkt[IP].sport
     dst=pkt[IP].dst
     dstport=pkt[IP].dport
     test=pkt[TCP].payload

     if HTTP.HTTPRequest in pkt:
        print "HTTP Request:"

        print test 
        print "======================================================================"
     if HTTP.HTTPResponse in pkt:
        print "HTTP Response:"
        print test 
        print "======================================================================"
```

### sniff(filter='tcp and port 80',iface=my_iface,prn=pktTCP)